# How Do I Lower My Polygon Count In Blender 2.8?

Tags: polycount

I Really Need Help, I Made A Dragon Egg Model And Need Help Lowering The Polygon Count

Comment: You could use the decimate modifier to cut down on the ploy count, depending on the detail of the object, this could result in a loss of detail.

Comment: can you add more information (e.g. a pic of the wires) and what the model is intended for?

Answer (score 1):

Select your object. Go to the modifiers tab (the one with the wrench icon)[image]
and set ratio to 0.5 (50%) with the option collapse active.
That means that whatever your polycount face is, will be reduced by half that number.